# Best way to analyse repeated measures with unequal time pts

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am interested how a dependent variable changes with time in relation to both between subject (random effects) and within subjects effects (fixed effects of seven fixed predictor variables). It is a retrospective analysis of observational data. I have 1500 individuals but a lot of missing data and unequal time points between individuals. Also 500 have 1 timepoint measurement, 700 just 2 timepoint measurements and 300 more than 2 timepoint measurements in the dependent variable. Is a mixed models analysis appropriate?

Comment: Yes, the mixed model is a good choice.